# Antisymmetric relation from a real life

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Would you know some examples of antisymmetric relation from a real life? That is, relation $$(x,y)\in R\quad 
 \text{and}\quad (y,x)\in R \rightarrow  x=y.$$ Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the set of all people set $(x,y) \in R$ if $x$ is the parent of $y$.

Then for any two people $x$ and $y$ it is not possible that $x$ is the parent of $y$ and that $y$ is the parent of $x$. Therefore the implication
$$(x,y) \in R \quad\text{and}\quad (y,x) \in R \implies x=y$$
is vacuously true so $R$ is antisymmetric.

Comment: "Twisted little monkey demon" ... I see what you mean by your profile description.

Comment: @Favst It's an amusing description of Tyrion Lannister from the book A Clash of Kings by G.R.R. Martin.

Answer (score 0):

The three most common elementary ones in my experience are:

1. Subset relation, like for geometric locus results
2. Real number inequalities
3. Divisibility of positive integers

These are all applicable in real life as long as the mathematical concepts model what you are looking at.

Comment: I mean some real situations. These are maths examples.

Comment: How about a set of weights say of 8, 4, 2, 1 and 1/2 ounces (or 100, 50, 10, 5, 1 grams, if you prefer) under the relation "not lighter than".

Comment: @dena antisymmetry is a mathematical concept. Any situation from real life that seems to use antisymmetry will inevitably use a mathematical version of antisymmetry that models that scenario. The one that Santos posted uses my second example, which is real number inequalities.

Answer (score 0):

Take the set of all floors from a building. If $f_1$ and $f_2$ are floors, consider$$f_1\mathrel Af_2\quad\text{if}\quad\text{$f_1$ is above than or equal to $f_2$}.$$Then $A$ is an antisymmetric relation.